# Objective-C property attributes best practices

Tags: objective-c, properties

After multiple searches and reads about property attributes, I still can't understand them completely and create a reflex of using them correctly.

I have multiple questions:

1) What does a `default` attribute mean?

As I understood, not specifying an attribute in a "group", the default one is used, so this:

```
@property NSString *string;
```

is `atomic`, right?

By this logic, [this article](http://rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2012/12/variable-property-attributes-or.html) says that `strong` and `assign` are defaults, so if I have:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *string;
```

is the `string` property `strong` or `assign`?

How are the available attributes "grouped"? Or as Xcode words this, what attributes are mutually exclusive?

2) Are there any generic rules that one should follow?

For example, I saw one comment that said that you should use `copy` for classes with mutable variants like `NSString`, `NSArray`.

And another one that said that you should use `assign` for C objects.

So, is it a good idea to always use:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *string;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat float;
```

?

What other standard practices exist for property attributes?

3) What problems could arise if I use "wrong" attributes? What if I just use `nonatomic` for all the properties in a project?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1a) The default attributes for a property are `atomic`, and `strong` (for an object pointer) or `assign` (for a primitive type), and `readwrite`. This assumes an all ARC project.

So `@property NSString *string;` is the same as `@property (atomic, strong, readwrite) NSString *string;`. `@property int value;` is the same as `@property (atomic, assign, readwrite) int value;`.

1b) Attributes are grouped as follows:

- atomic/nonatomic
- strong/weak/assign/copy
- readwrite/readonly

Pick one and only one from each of those three groups.

Actually, the latest Objective-C adds support for `nullable/nonnull` with the default being `nullable`.

2) General rules are as you say.

- Object pointers should usually be `strong`.
- Primitive types should be `assign`.
- `weak` should be used in child/parent references to avoid reference cycles. Typically the parent has a strong reference to its children and the children have a weak reference to their parent. Delegates are typically `weak` for the same reason.
- `copy` is typically used for `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, etc. to avoid issues when they are assigned the mutable variant. This avoids the problem of the value being changed unexpectedly.
- There's a big "gotcha" using `copy` with `NSMutableString`, `NSMutableArray`, etc. because when you assign the mutable value to the property, the `copy` attribute results in the `copy` method being called which gives back a non-mutable copy of the original value. The solution is to override the `setter` method to call `mutableCopy`.

3) Using the wrong attribute could have serious problems depending on the needs of the property and the attribute being used.

- Using `assign` instead of `strong` for an object pointer is probably the worst mistake. It can lead to app crashes due to trying to access deallocated objects.
- Using `nonatomic` instead of `atomic` on a property that will be accessed concurrently on multiple threads may lead to really hard to find bugs and/or crashes.
- Using `strong` instead of `copy` for `NSString` or `NSArray` (and other collections) can possibly lead to subtle and hard to find bugs if mutable variants were assigned to the property and other code later modifies those values.

Comment: Great answer. But, could you update it with answer to more questions? I want this to get the best answer regarding property attributes, as the current ones are heavily spread out over multiple existing questions, and most are old and outdated. So, For the point `2`, in other words, for primitive type, you never really need to write `assign`, because it's already a default, right? Great tip about mutable properties!

Comment: Good answer. Explaining a little more nullable/nonnull will make it perfect, even if they are new attributes.

Answer (score 4):

@rmaddy's answer is a good one.

I would add the following.

If you are creating (or have inherited) classes that interoperate with Swift, it is *very* useful to include `nullable` or `nonnull` property attributes. If you add it in any part of a header file, you will need to specify it for **all parts** of the header file (compiler warnings will help you).  It's even quite useful for Objective-C callers to know from the method signature what may and may not be a *nil* value.

Another property of note is `class`. You *can* add a property to the class.

Adding these two items together, and if you are implementing a singleton,

```
+ (MyClass *)sharedInstance;
```

it's quite useful to define it as a property:

```
@property (class, nonatomic, nonnull, readonly) MyClass *sharedInstance;
```

*(In which case you are required to add a backing variable for it as described [in this article](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/objective-c-class-properties/))*

This will let you access the shared instance via dot notation.

```
[MyClass.sharedInstance showMeTheMoney:YES];
```

And in Swift, the rather annoying

```
MyClass.sharedInstance()?.showMeTheMoney(true)
```

turns into

```
MyClass.sharedInstance.showMeTheMoney(true)
```

‡ maybe it's just 3 characters to you, but it keeps my head from exploding mid-day.

---

**Edit:**
I would add, try out

```
+ (instancetype)shared;
```

This 1) shortens the naming to concur with modern Swift convention, and 2) removes the hardcoded type value of a `(MyClass *)`.